# GAE jinja2 unable to import custom javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm working on a GAE project of my own,

and am trying to include my custom javascript file to one of my template files.

the directory structure is as follows:

- main dir
- app.yaml
- main.py
- templates

  - base.html
- javascript

  - myjavascript.js

I'm trying to include myjavascript.js from base.html

in my app.yaml, I specify:

```
-url: /javascript
 static_dir: javascript
```

and in base.html,

```
<script src = 'some src'> </script>
```

for 'some src', I've tried:

```
../javascript/myjavascript.js
/javascript/myjavascript.js
javascript/myjavascript.js
```

but it always gives me 404 (File not found) error.

I've also tried Jinja2's {% include /javascript/myjavascript.js %} and it gives me

IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible GAE

Can anyone help me with what's happening?

Thank you

Comment: I would expect `/javascript/myjavascript.js` to work here ... I'm guessing that the include doesn't work because it's in a static directory.  Static files are supposedly served from a different server, so your instance probably has no way of finding them -- i.e. I don't think the static files are stored with the regular ones.

Comment: @mgilson is correct that by default static files are not accessible from within the application code, however this is configurable: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#application_readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the handlers is important. Make sure that your `javascript` handler is before the `main` handler. Example:

```
handlers:
- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

From the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#handlers_1):

> Patterns are evaluated in the order they appear in the app.yaml, from top to bottom. The first mapping whose pattern matches the URL is the one used to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your yaml file

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf|pdf))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf|pdf))
```

instead of:

```
-url: /javascript
 static_dir: javascript
```

It will include all the files seperated by the pipe, but it will not downgrade your app

And if your base.html is in your templates directory and your javascript directory is in the same directory as the templates (your case) you should use ../javascript/myjavascript.js path, because the ".." stays for parent directory, and for the base.html file, the javascript directory is in the parent directory...

Comment: I tried that, and that blocks all my other stuff from working... It prevents me from inheriting from other templates

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my app.yaml files:

```
application: name-of-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf|pdf))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|ttf|pdf))
- url: .*
  script: name-of-app.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest                                                                      
- name: jinja2                                                                  
  version: latest                                                               
- name: markupsafe                                                              
  version: latest
```

Try to relate it with your app.yaml.